I2C: SDA and SCL Lines Pausing Between GND and VDD
I'm seeing communications on an I2C bus are momentarily pausing between GND and VDD (3.3V) during some transactions. See scope shot of the SDA line below:

Since it stops at about 800mV, this is below the logic low threshold for the devices on the bus, so it isn't really an issue per se. The I2C bus occasionally locks up, but I think that is a firmware issue. I see this intermediate step several times per I2C transaction and 99% of transactions succeed. I only see this happen on the SDA line, not SCL.
The rising edge of the intermediate steps always coincides with the rising edge of the SCL line. The intermediate step always begins to transition to the full VDD value with the rising edge of SCL. The SDA line can stay at this intermediate level for multiple clock edges (see second scope shot below, SDA yellow and SCL green):

The flatness and consistency of the intermediate steps almost suggests the behavior is intentional. Reminds me of de-emphasis used to preserve signal integrity on faster interfaces.
Setup details: nrf5240 talking to five different components. Using 4.7k pullups. Also tried 2.2k.
Any thoughts as to what might be causing this and how to better debug it? Is this even a problem?

Without seeing any code or hardware to verify, certaily looks like your IO pins are in push-pull mode, and it's incorrect. Or You have a hardware problem. Please check the code or post here. Schematics would help too. I will post an answer when enough info about the problem is gathered.

reduce the number of devices, check if all are setup for open drain, make sure that it is no two devices trying to drive the line via push-pull instead of open drain.

I am missing characteristic "RC" rising edge. It looks like that some device driving lines towards VCC "hard" (it looks like that some device on bus using Push-pull output instead open drain). That is dangerous an there is risk of short circuit between two or more devices on bus. Theese "steps between" can be result of that short circuit ("pull" transistor is typicaly stronger then "push" and therefore resulting voltage is not in mid between VCC and GND but closer to GND).

I appreciate the comments; they will help give new direction to my debug

Update: the issue was indeed due to the output being configured in push/pull rather than open drain. Thanks again.

@SchematicSavy - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an update. (a) Your update to the question said the cause was "the I2C pin's drive strength setting", but your comment said it was "due to the output being configured in push/pull rather than open drain". Those are different things. IMHO clarification would help. But... (b) FYI on Stack Exchange, questions should not be answered by editing the question. Instead, if something has been answered accidentally in comments (that shouldn't be done either - comments should not be used to answer questions) {...}

{...} then someone should post the solution as an actual answer. For example, you could post a self-answer (and áccept it, if no better answer has been posted - or if it has, then you can áccept that one). That self-answer should include quotes from, and links to, relevant comments which suggested the solution & links to their poster's usernames for attribution. You can explain how you confirmed their suggested solution. That way the question fits the Q&A format of SE (i.e. answers get posted as answers). Can you do that? TY

@SamGibson I'll add an answer clearing up the confusion my edit to the question made as well as undo that edit.

This issue was resolved by setting the nRF pins as open-drain (as suggested in comments by Justme and Christian B.) as well as by increasing the drive strength of the I2C pins from 'standard' to 'high.'
The nRf5240 GPIOs were being configured with the nrf_gpio_cfg function in the nRF SDK. One of the arguments for this function is drive. In order to set an open drain output, the 'disconnect' setting was used for the '0' logic level. For good measure, I also changed the '1' logic level to use the 'high' drive strength setting. This results in a value of NRF_GPIO_PIN_H0D1 being used for the drive parameter. These two changes eliminated the multi-level zero issues I was experiencing. I am not sure that using the 'high' drive strength setting for the '0' logic level was strictly necessary, but it is what I am currently using.
Although it wasn't applicable to my issue (since I wasn't using any I2C level shifters), Tom Carpenter's comment is a valuable one and I agree it is certainly something that should be investigated if your own circuitry is showing similar behavior.

Whether this applies here or not is unclear as the circuit is not specified. In case others have a similar issue, this sort of multi-level zero on I2C buses can be seen on circuits including level shifters such as the PCA9517 or similar part from other vendors.
These use an intentionally biased zero on one side (typically about 0.6V but some vendors chips may be higher) to allow the chip to determine which side of the shifter is trying to pull the bus low, so that it can control its direction.
From the datasheet linked above:

You can see this design marked on as the two different VOL levels in the diagram.
